# a protobuf problem about descriptor and reflection

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a problem. I want to make a very high frequency use of FieldDescriptor so I want to save FieldDescriptor address instead of calling FindFieldByName every time.

I found that the same protobuf object would share the same meta, they have the same FileDescriptor object and FieldDescriptor object.

Can I do that？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzq8B.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is safe (unless you are doing something funky).

When working with the interfaces generated by `protoc`, descriptors can safely be treated as permanent global variables, shared across messages.

It's a different matter when you are dealing with descriptors that come from other sources, like gRPC's reflection service for example. Even then, the lifetimes involved are generally straightforward.